# How to determine what is blocking a connection to website?

Tags: connection, ip, blocking

I need to connect, let's say a script, from an IP to a website and I can't, because:

```
wget: domain.com…
--2014-11-10 11:20:53-- domain.com…
recognized: domain.com... <IP>
Connecting with: domain.com|<IP>... error: Connection Timeout.
Connect again
```

I asked the admin of the server I host the domain on to give me ping and tracert to that IP and here it is:

```
pat@daz:/# ping 188.127.246.50
PING 188.127.246.50 (188.127.246.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 188.127.246.50 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1009ms


pat@daz:/# traceroute 188.127.246.50
traceroute to 188.127.246.50 (188.127.246.50), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
1 79.133.193.65 (79.133.193.65) 1.348 ms 0.994 ms 0.796 ms
2 ae1-JunM10.etop.pl (79.133.201.129) 72.054 ms 56.309 ms 52.532 ms
3 frm-k90-cr1.rascom.ru (80.81.192.166) 20.489 ms 20.356 ms 20.388 ms
4 * * *
5 oversun.w-ix.net (193.106.112.195) 63.164 ms 59.526 ms 124.898 ms
6 * * *
7 * *^C
```

The website's .htaccess is clean, robots.txt too, hosting's admin says there's nothing from their side (firewall, blacklist etc) that could be blocking that IP from connecting.

What could it be then? How can I check it?

Comment: What about the firewall on your side?

Comment: Hosting's admin says there's nothing that could be blocking that IP from connecting.